# Web Api that creates another Api in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

My requirement is to create a web api in c# that will create another API According to the document. 
User will send api name, action method name , Request and type of operation that need to be performed by the new api and our api will create the required api and return response that contain API url and request/response type.

I have searched in lot of different website but i did't found anything related to it. if anyone have solution of it or any close idea please share. i need to do this in asp.net MVC

Comment: This is a really broad question, and in general the architecture you are trying to design will be overly complex, highly insecure, and virtually impossible to maintain.  What is the purpose of this design decision?  Who is the intended user of this system, that both knows enough about the code to know what your data structures are like to need custom APIs, but at the same time doesn't have the ability to add their desired API to the server code directly?

Comment: In general i have to make lot Api's everyday (3-4 api's per day) for my project, basically for crud operation etc. so to save time in making of these api i decided to make a API that will create API. i know this is not something that i can do in 1-2 day. but i think somehow it is possible to create this kind of application.
 Thank you for your concern.

Comment: This isn't really the right way to solve that kind of problem, though.  If you are trying to save your self work in repetition or constant re-use of boilerplate code, you might want to take a look at tools that are designed to handle this kind of thing, like PostSharp, for example.

Comment: Yes, i think you are right, wasting time in making this application is not worth for me. and i guess i am not enough to make this application alone. PostSharp is a good option, i think i should go for it. thanks for your advice.

Comment: What'll be the content of the api action? I think the new AI overlords will be able to create this kind of API that'll create children APIs on whim easily.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is too vague

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample program that uses CodeDomCompiler that generates a standard Telemetry implementation for any given interface.  The code is compiled to memory and loaded into the address space.  This sounds like what you are trying to do.  If so, take stab at generating some code using the samples and ask questions as you encounter problems.

This may help you get started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using TelemeterFactory;

namespace ConsoleTelemeter
{
    /// <summary>Generate a CSharp Telemeter that calls Console.WriteLine as its output.</summary>
    public class Factory : FactoryBase
    {
        public override string[] GenerateSource(SourceGenerationOptions options)
        {
            var generatedClassName = options.Type.Name + "_" + options.FactoryOptions.ClassName;

            var text = this.CSharpTemplate()
                .Replace("<codeGenerationTool>", $"{nameof(ConsoleTelemeter)} {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version} {DateTimeOffset.UtcNow:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz}")
                .Replace("<generatedNamespace>", options.FactoryOptions.Namespace)
                .Replace("<generatedClassName>", generatedClassName)
                .Replace("<interfaceImplemented>", options.Type.FullName)
                .Replace("//<privateFields>", "private const string Null = \"<null>\";")
                .Replace("//<publicMethodImplementations>", Methods(options.Methods))
                .Replace("\t", "    ")
                ;

            return new[] { text, $"{options.FactoryOptions.Namespace}.{generatedClassName}" };
        }

        private string Methods(IReadOnlyList<MethodInfo> methods)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
            foreach (var method in methods)
            {
                // method start
                sb.AppendFormat("\n\t\tpublic {0} {1} (", method.ReturnType, method.Name);
                var comma = string.Empty;
                foreach (ParameterInfo parameter in method.GetParameters())
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1} {2}", comma, parameter.ParameterType, parameter.Name);
                    comma = ", ";
                }
                sb.Append(") {\n");

                sb.Append("\t\t\tvar result = $\"{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff} ");
                sb.Append("{nameof(");
                sb.Append(method.Name);
                sb.Append(")}: ");

                comma = string.Empty;
                foreach (ParameterInfo parameter in method.GetParameters())
                {
                    var t = parameter.ParameterType;
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}{{nameof({1})}}={{", comma, parameter.Name);

                    // special case for boolean parameters to be coerced to strings below.  Not strictly necessary for this Telemeter but show how one could do it if necessary.
                    sb.AppendFormat("{1}{0}", parameter.Name, t == typeof(Boolean) ? "(" : string.Empty);

                    if (t == typeof(string))
                    {
                        sb.Append(" ?? Null");
                    }
                    else if (t == typeof(Int32) 
                         || t == typeof(float) 
                         || t == typeof(double)
                         || t == typeof(Int64)
                         || t == typeof(decimal)
                         || t == typeof(Int16))
                    {
                        sb.Append(":#0");
                    }
                    else if (t.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
                    {
                        sb.Append(":D");
                    }
                    else if (t == typeof(Boolean))
                    {
                        sb.Append("? \"1\" : \"0\")");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(".ToString() ?? Null");
                    }

                    sb.Append("}");
                    comma = ",";
                }

                sb.Append("\";\n\t\t\treturn result;\n");

                // method end
                sb.Append("\t\t}\n");
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```